# Add Filtering in matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, filter, scatter-plot

I'm using matplotlib scatter plot for tSNE visualization and I want to filter my results by class.
For example this one plot and I want to have an option to see only label 15000 samples:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUy6X.png)

Is it an option? Can you please lead my way?
Thanks

Comment: Do you get labels for your t-SNE result? not clear in your question

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is not necessarily in matplotlib, but in the dataframe you choose to plot. After you complete your tSNE analysis, you can choose the subset of that resulting dataframe that only includes the class you're interested in. If you can provide a sample of that dataframe I'd be more than happy to provide some code as well.

Comment: Thanks,  tsne = manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=100.0, init='pca', random_state=0,n_jobs=-1)
        Y = tsne.fit_transform(data) 
So I got 2 column ndarray as data and given labels as 
" class_labels = pd.DataFrame(class_labels).to_numpy"